# Question Relating Gamma Function to Riemann Zeta function evaluated at integers

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I was just reading a paper of Ramanujan entitled *"On question 330 of Professor Sanjana"* when I got confused regarding a proposition which I am unable to answer. The proposition is:

$ \displaystyle f(p) = \frac{\pi}{2^{p+1}} \frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{ \Bigl[ \Gamma(\frac{P+2}{2}) \Bigr]^{2}}$, then $$\log{f(p)}= \log(\frac{\pi}{2}) - p\log{2}  + \frac{p^2}{2} \Bigl(1-\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)S_{2} - \frac{p^3}{3} \Bigl(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\Bigr)S_{3} + \cdots$$

where $\displaystyle S_{n} = \frac{1}{1^n} + \frac{1}{2^n} + \cdots \text{ad inf.}$

Could anyone explain me as to how can i deduce this.

Comment: $S_n$ is called [the (Riemann) zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: @Kenny TM: Yes, it didn't strike my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume this is a Maclaurin series. I don't know how it comes
about, but my instinct would be to expand out the infinite product
for $f(p)$ (which becomes an infinite sum for $\log f(p)$) in powers
of $p$.

**Added** (13/8/2010)
As a hint: recall that
$$\Gamma(p+1)=p\Gamma(p)
=e^{-\gamma p}\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n}{n+p}\right)e^{p/n}$$
by the infinite product for the gamma function. Applying
this to $\Gamma(p+1)/\Gamma(p/2+1)^2$ one gets some nice
cancellation. Then take logs and apply the series for $\log(1+x)$.
You get a double sum; change the order of summation and hope that
the inner sum comes to something like a zeta series.

Comment: @Robin Chapman: I shall get back to you once i finish working out the details. Meanwhile, there was a reference in the article, it stated "vide( Carr's Synopsis 2295)". Now i don't know what is that.

Comment: http://www.archive.org/details/asynopsiselemen00carrgoog

Comment: @Robin Chapman: The view is abstruse and i am unable to locate it.  We also can't use th ctrl+F command to find the text

Comment: Carr's *Synopsis* was Ramanujan's mathematical bible
in his youth. Alas the link above leads only to the
first of its two volumes, and naturally section 2295 is
in the second volume :-)

Still, it would do you good to derive it yourself,
from the infinite product for the gamma function :-)

Comment: Ah, Okay. By the way, i guess it's not too tough, and involves basic calculations.

Comment: [Carr's Synopsis 2295 is here](http://books.google.com/books?id=JLmCAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA360). It states that $\log \Gamma(1+n) = (\log\mu - S_1)n + \frac12S_2n^2 - \frac13S_3n^3 + \dots$. Its notation is that µ is "an indefinitely great integer", and it's too late at night for me to parse what that means, but there's a sketch of the proof at the end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at equation 34 on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html After taking the log of both sides, the zeta function appears in essentially the same form as in your equation. They reference a 1968 paper by Wrench for more information. I haven't worked through the details myself, but the similarities are striking, and it looks like a promising approach.